# Railway. NGINX. 413 Request Entity Too Large. Laravel app

Tags: laravel, nginx, docker-compose, laravel-sail, railway

i am deploying an app in Railway that handles file uploads. I get this error if the file is greater than 1mb.

I have tried this solutions but i dont have a /etc/nginx folder anywhere

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436314/413-request-entity-too-large-nginx-1-8-1](https://stackoverflow.com)
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43182944/nginx-413-request-entity-too-large](https://stackoverflow.com)

My guess is that this must be a configuration on the Docker image.

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./docker/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.2/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
            - "client_max_body_size 20M;"
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
```

Any idea how to set the size limit to 20mb?

Thanks

Increase the size limit to 20mb